# How to use WebApi in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a project that based on database columns selection, will present those columns as charts in a browser web page.

i have been reading about `WebApi` (i've been told to use it with a windows form project) and for my problem i can't figure out which is the better (easy) aprouch.

The charts are created with javascript and in with the windows form i collect the database connection values (server, username,...) and the columns that will be selected for the charts.

My questions are:

1. do i call the webapi from javascript sending the column name and receving the values to use?

   - if so how can i send the column name from my windows form to javascript?
2. do i call it from my windows form and do all the work in the webapi and present it using the cshtml files that the webapi has?

   - if so how can i call the webapi from my windows form (present the cshtml file)?
   - how to send the data i need (columns names) to it? (i've seen also `HttpClient`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web service (implemented by a Web API project) will return the data (e.g. comma-separated, JSON, or XML) to your local app (a web service per definition has no UI, otherwise it would be a website app). What your local app then does with the retrieved data, is a completely other thing.

And yes, it's of course possible to call a web service from JS. A web service URL is just a normal URL and can be handled like any other one. Google is your friend on that - you may use  jQuery, it has some convenient shortcuts for this task.

Comment: and how can i send a string (column names as json) to javascript from my windows form, so from there can send it to webapi? can you give me a code example?

Comment: Just send your column names as regular URL parameters (comma-sep. is better than JSON in this case), like you would do it in a normal web app. The MVC framework will do the rest...

Comment: but how can i do that, since my solution as 2 projects (windows form an webapi) and the column names are collected in my windows form?

Comment: You can use a REST framework like e.g. RestSharp to submit an URL request (and receive the results, of course) from within other code. (RestSharp is available as NuGet package, or just google it)

Comment: is there a code example that you can provide me with? calling the web api, sending the data and receving it on the other side?
thk

Comment: Not at hand, I would need to google for it, so I leave that up to you ;-). Just search for 'web service ASP.NET MVC web api' and 'RestSharp example' and you will get tons of code examples.